# Recursively search for a file on a website w/ Directory Browsing

Tags: python, urllib

Is there a way to locate if a file or directory exists on a web server with http directory browsing?  I have a site which contains a number of files and directories. I want to traverse the directories and find a given file that can be located anywhere in the sub-directories. Normally we can do that using `os.path.isfile("file_name")` on a file system, but this does not work with directory browsing on HTTP. How can we do that?

Comment: I just noticed you have identical questions posted on this same issue – you may want to delete those.

Answer (score 3):

Doing that on the web is not as straightforward as doing it w/ a file system.  For one thing there will be differences in the folder listing depending on what web-server it is.  SO you have to KNOW how the listing is formatted.  For example a pattern I noticed w/ most linux/apache servers is that folders end with a slash ‘/’ files don’t.  The parent folder starts with a slash, folders don’t… etc…

This is just an example (that does work) that should get you started in the right direction.  To run the example you must install [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/)

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def RecurseLinks(base):

    f = urllib.request.urlopen(base)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(f.read())
    for anchor in soup.find_all('a'):
        href = anchor.get('href')
        if (href.startswith('/')):
            print ('skip, most likely the parent folder -> ' + href)
        elif (href.endswith('/')):
            print ('crawl -> [' + base + href + ']')
            RecurseLinks(base + href) # make recursive call w/ the new base folder
        else:
            print ('some file, check if xyz.txt -> ' + href) # save it to a list or return 

# call the initial root web folder
RecurseLinks('http://somesite-xyx.com.com/directory-browsing/')
```